# Can we have one set of SharePoint 2013 servers in On-Premises and another set in Azure

Tags: sharepoint-server, azure, load-balancing

Is it possible to have one set of SharePoint 2013 servers (WFE, APP and DB) and another set of servers in Azure? Can we configure load balancing between the servers hosted in On-Premises and Azure? I found the architecture to configure Disaster recovery between On-premises and Azure. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn635313.aspx

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not recommend these types of architecture ("stretched" farm).

**Check this links:**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748824(v=office.15).aspx#CfgStretchedFarm

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sambetts/archive/2014/04/17/high-availability-sharepoint-stretched-sharepoint-farms-vs-disaster-recovery-sharepoint-farms.aspx

You can use azure blob storage for your´s datafiles in on-premise:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2014/08/25/implementing-azure-blob-storage-abs-with-sql-server-2014-and-sharepoint-2013.aspx